# -webkit-scrollbar styling on an iframe not working

Tags: css, iframe, webkit

Trying to change the colors of the scrollbar on this iframe isn't working. It seems to be because it is an iframe, because this [demo](http://codepen.io/devstreak/pen/dMYgeO) on webkit scrollbars breaks when a div is [changed to an iframe](http://codepen.io/kimholder/pen/BpbBGY). So, is it something that can't be done with CSS in this case? I tried putting the webkit CSS on the page in the iframe, and that didn't work either.

```css
iframe::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: black; }
```

```html
  <iframe src="https://www.moonwards.com/2016/02/04/test-test.html" width="100%" style="border:none;" ></iframe>
```